# why using DecodeStream(stream) take longer time in a thread than it is in main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, image-processing

I am trying to receive image stream from desktop in the android phone. When I put decodeStream() method in my thread, then put decodestream() into  runOnuiThread() to display in the imageView, it takes more than 7 secs. But when I try to directly read image from asset, and convert into inputstream, then decodeStream(), it may take 500ms, I don't know why it happens. The image is 100K.

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SocketConnect = new socketConnect();
            SocketConnect.connectsocket("134.129.125.126", 8080);
            while (true) {
                data = new byte[2048 * 2048];

                try {
                    read = SocketConnect.getInputStream().read(data, 0,
                            data.length);
                    input = SocketConnect.getInputStream();
                    System.out.println("getInputStream()");
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    System.out.println("decodestream()");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        System.out.println("setImage at less than 500");

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

client side should sent the image very 5 sec.
If I try to read same image from asset, Image display immedately.

```
try {
     inputasset=getAssets().open("good1.jpg");
     Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputasset);    
     image.setImageBitmap(bit);
     } catch (IOException e) {
      TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

socketConnect class

```
    public class socketConnect {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private InputStream input;
    private Bitmap bMap;

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return input;
    }

    public void connectsocket(String ipString, int port)

    {
        System.out.println("starts");

        try {
            // clientSocket = new Socket("134.129.125.172",8080);
            System.out.println("starts");
            clientSocket = new Socket(ipString, port);

            System.out.println("AsyncTask: Connect to 134.129.125.126");
            input = clientSocket.getInputStream();

            System.out.println("AsyncTask: get the inputStream");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: right now I am trying to make conversion is not delay, why delay only happens in threading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                read = SocketConnect.getInputStream().read(data, 0,
                        data.length);
                input = SocketConnect.getInputStream();
                System.out.println("getInputStream()");
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                System.out.println("decodestream()");
```

You read the data from the input stream, then you ask the BitmapFactory to read the data from the input stream. But you already read it! Remove the call to `read` -- you're stealing data from the BitmapFactory.

Comment: Also it looks like you're downloading the image from a remote server whereas the assets folder is right on the device.  That's going to take longer no matter what.

Comment: @user3799770 One bug at a time.

Comment: After I remove, it keep infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the server side is not properly signaling that the end of the file has been reached. I've encountered this previously because the web server implementation might not tell you the length of the file it is sending. If it doesn't set the content length then the input stream keeps trying to read forever. My guess is that it takes a number of minutes because this is the default socket timeout value.

So, the input stream from the socket reads as much as it can and keeps waiting for more data. After waiting several minutes (although usually 5 minutes is the default timeout) the socket closes and you get your image.

I'm not entirely sure that a content length will help, another option might be that the server closes the connection after all the data is sent.

Clearly, if you're trying to stream new images though, you need to do something different than you are. Perhaps have your server send a file header that the reader interprets. This header might include the length of the data being sent and then the client you write stops reading after reaching this length. In this case you'll need to read the image data into a buffer and then have the BitmapFactory read the buffer instead of the stream.

An alternate approach would have the server close the connection after sending the data for each image and then the client would reconnect to get the next one.

Bottom line, not all InputStreams are created equal and a SocketInputStream doesn't know when to close without a content length or the socket being closed.